# Is there a program to simulate spotty network connection?

Tags: networking

Is there a program to simulate spotty network connection? 
I would turn it on while I test my apps, to ensure they can handle network failure.

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094760/network-tools-that-simulate-slow-network-connection

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to fine-tune the spottiness, then tor + privoxy is a good simulation in my experience, though they were designed for a completely different purpose.

Comment: How is Tor spotty? It are just more hops, but it doesn't really introduce *failure*.

Comment: My understanding is highly variable thru put which Tor tends to introduce. My own experience with Tor in any case.